# How do I properly store multiple checkboxed values using SimpleForm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, enums, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

Basically I want to create an option in my form that accepts checkboxes (0 to all values accepted).

I love the structure of enums, because I get the performance speed of storing the integer in the DB, but I can reference the symbol in my code. However, I doubt I can use enum when I am storing multiple values like a checkbox.

So the way I imagine it working best is to just store it as a string that is also an array. So something like this:

```
#  refactor_rule           :string           default([]), is an Array
```

Then my form looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :refactor_rule, collection: ["dry", "concise", "performant"], as: :check_boxes, class: "form-control" %>
```

The issue with this approach is when I store just 1 or 2 of the options (i.e. not all), this is what the attribute looks like:

```
q.refactor_rule
=> ["", "dry", "concise"]
```

Which I hate, because of the empty value at `[0]`.

So my questions are as follows:

1. What's the most performant way to achieve this? Note that the options in my checkbox are static, but the field needs to accept multiple not 1?
2. How do I only store the values checked and not empty values?
3. Is there any way to take advantage of Rails built-in enum functionality even though I am storing multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always have something like this to "clean" your attributes :

```
q.refactor_rule.reject!(&:empty?)
```

Which is gonna reject all empty elements from you array. Mind the `!`. `reject!` replaces it without the empty elements, `reject` just returns it. Your call !

If you really need to store an array in database, you can do it like so, in your migration :

```
create_table :products do |t|
   t.text :tags, array: true, default: []
end
```

(This is from [this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/) from Plataformatec)

Comment: If I don't use an `array` in the DB, how do I store it? A string? I have already set it up as an array in the db.

Comment: You don't want to store this as a string, as you're gonna have to decode it every time you want to read / update this. If it makes sense for you, make another model (called "RefactorRule" maybe), with a relationship `has_many :refactor_rules`. This way, you'll be able to use the power of association and use Rails at its full speed :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an enum (performant but allows only a single value to be stored) or a serialized array (slow and storage space demanding) you should **consider storing the boolean values as a bit field**. This approach converts multiple boolean values (flags) to a single integer column where each flag has its own bit position in the integer. This of course has a massive positive impact on performance - you can search for any combination of flags using the [`&` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and) (in MySQL) instead of trying to search for substrings in a text column.

Take a look at the **[`flag_shih_tzu`](https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu)** or the **[`bitfields`](https://github.com/grosser/bitfields)** gems. Both gems enhance Active Record so that all flags act like separate "virtual" attributes of a model object and they provide convenient methods for searching through such attributes. For this to work you probably would have to rewrite the simple_form form to use 3 separate check boxes instead of a single one though.

Comment: Interesting...thanks for giving me this option. I probably won't go this route, but it is interesting to explore.